# difference between Installing bootstrap and including its recommanded files to html file

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-sass

I'm a beginner in web development and i'm confused,i'm learning Bootsrap by doing a project (develop a portfolio with bootstrap and Sass), the problem is described as follow:
1- we installed nodejs
2- we used the npm to install some packages (Sass / and Bootstrap)
3-while beginning the project, we included the bootstrap js file in the html file in which we are working

this is the file:

The question is , why did we need to implement this file while we were already installed Bootsrap, i think that the installation does the job and no nead to further implementations??!!!

is there any differences between implementation and installation, and what the installation of bootstrap really do!!!???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You install packages to have access to their functions and sometimes their css code to use them in your projects . For example you install bootstrap you actually download it's minified css file so you need to import that css in your project and use it's classes for elements .

Comment: yeh, i understand , but if the whole necessary files are already downloaded when we installed Bootstrap, why did we have to implement the js file address token from bootstrap website.  it should be installed with bootstrap!?

Comment: @nourEmely For the js files of bootstrap no you don't need to include a cdn script from the bootstrap site in your html but only you can import them in your components .